# Problems with Different versions of IE on joomla

Tags: joomla3.2

my Joomla website work's on some IE10 , but it's not working properly on some IE10 and bellow. how can I find the problem

Comment: Should we consider all the research that you shared, I would go with "Hire a professional". Or do your homework and write a proper question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the debug option in the IE10. previously i had used the IE7 standard. now i switch over to IE9 standard and its working fine. you can find this option with F12 key